# Reach two IBOutlets of NSTextField at once

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, nstextfield

I have a login-page with two NSTextFields, so I created two @IBOutlets in my viewcontroller. For some styling I have to call both of them. I want to give them the same properties, but I dont want to call them individual. So how can I reach them at once to give them a property like `inputFields.isBordered = true`

For iOS swift provides `@IBOutletCollection` but for MacOS not.

```
    @IBOutlet weak var emailInput: NSTextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var passwordInput: NSTextField!

    override func viewWillAppear() {

        emailInput.isBordered = true
        passwordInput.isBordered = true

    }
```

So I want two call them like `inputFields.isBordered = true` and not individual.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this in many different ways. For example:

```
func modifyTextFields(_ closure: (NSTextField) -> Void) {
    closure(emailInput)
    closure(passwordInput)
}

// usage:
modifyTextFields { $0.isBordered = true }
```

Alternatively,

```
var textFields: [NSTextField] { // this kind of works like an outlet collection
    return [emailInput, passwordInput]
}

// usage:
textFields.forEach { $0.isBordered = true }
```